# Solving an equation with boundary conditions to find coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, boundary-value-problem

I want to find the unknown constants in the function $f(x,y)=A(e^{-i.k_{x}x}+C_{1}x+C_{2})(e^{-i.k_{y}y}+C_{3}y+C_{4})$, using the following known boundary conditions and auxiliary equation (contraint), where $A, C_{1}, C_{2}, C_{3}, C_{4}$ are the wanted unknown constants (coefficients) and $(x,y)$ are the independent variables.

The conditions are: $(\partial f/\partial y)_{y=0}=(\partial f/\partial y)_{y=y_{0}}=(\partial f/\partial x)_{x=0}=(\partial f/\partial x)_{x=x_{0}}=0$

The auxiliary equation (contraint) is: $\int\limits^{u_{2}}_{u_{1}}\int\limits^{v_{2}}_{v_{1}}f((u-v)/\sqrt{2},(u+v)/\sqrt{2})du dv$. Note that this is simply integrating $f(x,y)$ but after changing variables to: $x=(u-v)/\sqrt{2}$ and $y=(x+v)/\sqrt{2}$.

Note that $x_{0},y_{0},u_{1},u_{2},v_{1},v_{2}$ are all known constants.

The number of unknown constants ($A, C_{1}, C_{2}, C_{3}, C_{4}$) in the function $f$ is 5. The number of expressions given above (1 equation and 4 boundary conditions) is also 5. So, in principle, we should be able to find these constants (coefficients).

How do I determine these constants from the information given above? One way I thought of is to re-arrange the resulting 5 expressions in matrix form, ordered by these coefficients, then enforce a nontrivial solution by taking the determinant = zero. However, two questions arise here:

1- How to re-write these expressions in terms of these coefficients (constants)? Especially if some terms have more than one (mixed) coefficients, like say $C_{1}C_{3}$ or $AC_{3}$?

2- Is there an easy way to make this using a computer tool (Mathematica or MATLAB)? If so, please indicate how?

I am also open to other suggestions on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, the equations will not be linear wrt the parameters. It would be interesting to see your equations since, may be, some rearrangements could be done.

Comment: @Claude Thanks. The function $f$ was chosen as a general solution to a Helmholtz equation $\partial^{2}f/\partial x^{2}+\partial^{2}f/\partial y^{2}+k^{2}f=0$ and $f=f(x,y)$. I arrived at this and the rest of the BCs using standard variational techniques. However,I've a small gap in my domain (the rectangle $x\in[0,x_{0}]$ and $y\in[0,y_{0}]$) and that gap is rectangular but rotated 45 degrees, so it is easy to describe it in the rotated coordinates $(u,v)$, which are used in the aux eqn above. So the constaint is to have $f=0$ across the gap, hence my choice of aux eqn above. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am totally not familiar with this. Could you post the equations or send me an e-mail ? Cheers.